# Writing a python script to counts the number of airports in each country, but getting following error 'string indices must be integers, not str'

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python programming, I am trying to count the number of airports in each country. I am getting an error can someone help me resolve the following issue

```
import csv
f = open("airports.dat")
for lists in csv.reader(f):
    airports = lists[1]
    countries = lists[3]

for air in airports:
    if air not in airports:
        airports[air]=1
    else:
        airports[air]+=1
print(airports)
```

Getting following error -

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-df427e17a15c> in <module>()
      6 
      7 for air in airports:
----> 8     if air not in airports(airports):
      9         airports[air]=1
      10     else:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Your code and error are not in sync

Comment: Are you sure `airports` is a dictionary and not a list?

Comment: Show the first few lines of your file. That way it will be quicker to solve.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect `air not in airports` to be true? You're literally iterating over `for air in airports`, by definition, `air` will **always** be in `airports`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for `csv.reader`:

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given *csvfile*.
>
> ...
>
> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.

This means that `lists` in your code below will actually refer to a *list* (not plural!) of strings:

```
for lists in csv.reader(f):
```

This means that you're assigning a *string* to `airports`:

```
airports = lists[1]
```

And that in turn means this code is iterating over each character in a string:

```
for air in airports:
```

Since a string is a sequence (of characters), you get a `TypeError` as you're attempting to access an element of this sequence with a non-integral subscript value (specifically, a single character):

```
airports[air]+=1
```